# Selenium java trying to click list element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test delta.com site via selenium webDriver and I'm stuck on the passenger info page, instructions how to get to it below. Everything goes just fine except that I can't select any list fields. List opens, programm doesn't select anything and goes further.

So for example I'm trying to select gender.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"gender0-button\"]/span[1]")
private WebElement genderSelection;
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id="gender0-menu"]/li[2]")
private WebElement genderMale;

public void setGender(){
    genderSelection.click();
    genderMale.click();
}
```

But it doesn't select anything, goes further.

Then I tried to use `<select>` that is hidden, xpath = "//*[@id="gender0"]". There I click on the option with 'male' text. Doesn't work too.

Then I tryed javascript. There are some attributes in `<span>` that change if I manually change to 'Male'. So i do smth like this (id to set can vary):

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = 'Male'", genderMale);
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('gender0-button').setAttribute('aria-activedescendant', 'ui-id-74')");
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('gender0-button').setAttribute('aria-lablelledby', 'gender0-label ui-id-74 gender0-required')");
```

This doesn't work too. It sets text into span, but then I still get error that I havn't filled gender field.

So may be someone knows how set at least gender.

How to get to passenger info page: Book a trip -> Flight -> Round trip -> From-to(I select JFK-SVO) -> any dates this month -> Exact dates -> Money -> Find flights -> select any tickets types -> Continue -> you are there.

Edit 1.
[HTML of the page](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Ouy1UuPsA8amxvUUhvaUJPZlU)

Comment: It would be better if you paste html directly in here

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to include your code for getting to the page. The easier you make it for others to work on your problem the more likely they'll be willing to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I needed to highlight 'Male' option and then click.

```
genderSelection.click();
genderMale.sendKeys("Male");
genderMale.click();
```